# Keep select2 open only on shift-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

I use select2 to add tags. There is an option to keep the select list open on selecting an item (`closeOnSelect`), but how can I make this happen only if the shift key is pressed while selecting it? Try setting `closeOnSelect` to `false` to see what I want to happen only when the shift key is pressed.

Here's a list of API options: https://select2.org/configuration/options-api

Here's a list of events: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events

```js
$(".form-control").select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    closeOnSelect: true
})
.on('select2:select', function (e) {
    // How can I reach shiftKey here?
    if( e.shiftKey )
    {
        alert('How do I make closeOnSelect: false happen here?');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
  <option selected="selected">orange</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option selected="selected">purple</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two choices.
You may don't know, but `select2` seems to have a similar function; it checks if the control key is being held.
Let's see [select2.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.js), and search `// Don't close if the control key is being held`.
I think it's easy that you modify that part of the plugin directly, rather than implement yourself.
(I couldn't find the way of overwriting the function.)

However, I'm also found the way.
But maybe sometimes can't prevent to close `select2` ...

Firstly, you need to `keydown` and `keyup` event at the 2 part.

```
// jQuery keydown doesn't work for some reason.(It seems this plugin is a bit tricky.)
// This event is used when the text box has focus.
document.getElementsByClassName('select2-search__field')[0].onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 16) {
        isShiftDown = true;
    }
}
document.getElementsByClassName('select2-search__field')[0].onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 16) {
        isShiftDown = false;
    }
}

// This event is used when the text box doesn't has focus.
$(window).on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 16) {
        isShiftDown = true;
    }
}).on("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 16) {
        isShiftDown = false;
    }
});
```

Secondly, add `closing` event.

```
// Closing (if you return false in this event, select2 doesn't close.)
.on('select2:closing', function () {
    // To be exact, there's no need to return true.
    return !isShiftDown;
});
```

Of course, even though you success to implement, the Ctrl key function still exists.
[For Example.](https://jsfiddle.net/xdgw1sat/9/)

***UPDATED***
Add logic, considering "If it's multiple" and "If it isn't present". Just in case.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('select2-search__field');
if (inputs.length > 0) {
    for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].onkeydown = function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 16) {
                isShiftDown = true;
            }
        }
        inputs[i].onkeyup = function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 16) {
                isShiftDown = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising! Thanks! I got this message `TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined` I tried to put it in `window.onload = function() ` and the message disappeared, but it doesn't seem to fire for the select2. I also got a `ReferenceError: isShiftDown is not defined` which disappeared after adding `var isShiftDown = false;` at the top. Is there anything I need to think of in terms of order of all of these? Thanks!

Comment: Ha, it's actually working! The problem was that I have a bunch of select2s that I want to apply it on and only the first one works. I tried some randon ones later on. How can I apply the same shift trick on every select with a certain class? Thanks again!

Comment: I updated your jsfiddle :) How can I get it to work on both of them? And in a way that it's only select2 of the same class, since there will be other select2 boxes that it shouldn't affect.

Comment: I also get the `document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefine` message on pages where no select2s are present. Any way to apply it only if they exist?

Comment: Sorry for spamming here, but I did what you said and changed the source code to `if (originalEvent && (originalEvent.ctrlKey || originalEvent.shiftKey) )` and it works great! It doesn't matter if it applies to every select2 when I think about it. Thanks again!

Comment: If multiple, you need the same logic, like document.getElementsByClassName(...)[1]...(this is the same as $(".class")). Anyway, it seems that changing the plugin is the best way. I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Just in case, I updated my answer and the jsfiddle's URL.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it is because the select2's events happen before jQuery that it didn't work using jQuery? I've been in a similar situation before.

Comment: I just realize that `jQuery's key event` work until I append the item. I checked the `keydown` event using a developer tool. and noticed the event was deleted when I append the item. I don't know why normal javascript event can avoid deleting, though.